# v-autocomplete lost "change event" in vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

In Vuetify 2 there was a **change event** for the v-autocomplete component. An example:

```
<v-autocomplete
    label="Choose stock"
    v-model="selected_stock"
    :items="current_stocks"
    :change="stockSelected"
    item-value="id" 
    item-title="name"></v-autocomplete>

stockSelected(selected_stock) {
   console.log(selected_stock);
}
```

In Vuetify 3 this event doesn't seem to exist anymore. How can I **track a selection change** in Vuetify 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the `@change` event was removed because it is redundant, you can just listen to the `@update:modelValue` event:

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="selected_stock"
    @update:modelValue="stockSelected"
    ...
></v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: I cant get the update:modelValue event to fire. Neither hitting enter nor selecting something with my mouse will fire it... Any idea?

Comment: @dturnschek Are you using the DOM as template? You'd have to use kebap case then (`@update:model-value`). There are other pitfalls, see [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#in-dom-template-parsing-caveats)