# Vue3 @input function not getting called on autocomplete text input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this code snippet in a Vue3 component:

```
<v-row
    v-for="(target, targetIndex) in targetModules"
    :key="targetIndex"
>
    <v-autocomplete
          v-model="targetModules[targetIndex]['modulName']"
          :items="moduleNamesAndEcts.map(module => module.name)"
          :rules="rules.text"
          label="Module"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="name"
          @input="(newModuleName) => updateEcts(newModuleName, targetIndex)"
        />
</v-row>
```

The function is:

```
const updateEcts = (newModuleName, targetIndex) => {
        console.log("HELLO!")
        const module = moduleNamesAndEcts.value.find(module => module.name === newModuleName);
        console.log(module.ects)
        if (module) {
            targetModules[targetIndex]['creditPoints'] = module.ects;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, `updateEcts` doesn't seem to get called. The `console.log` doesn't get printed. `@change` also didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: In your @input your calling a `updateIndex` function, not `updateEcts`

Comment: Edited, I had copied it wrong from another attempt.

Comment: Can you add what the `targetModules` and `moduleNamesAndEcts` vars look like

Comment: `moduleNamesAndEcts` is a `computed` property, if I console log it I get the following structure inside `_value`:
`0: { ects : "5",
name: "Algorithms" }`
And the other one is `const targetModules = ref([{ modulName: "", creditPoints: null, moduleDescription: null }])`

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. [This does work](https://shorturl.at/euvK4)

Comment: are they any errors in console that could be halting or preventing code execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such events like `input` or `change` in the [VAutocomplete API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#vautocomplete-api).

**You should use [`update:modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#events-update:modelValue) instead**. Here is a list with all the [VAutocomplete API events](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#events).

Your `v-autocomplete` should look like this:

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="targetModules[targetIndex]['modulName']"
  :items="moduleNamesAndEcts.map(module => module.name)"
  :rules="rules.text"
  label="Module"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="name"
  @update:modelValue="(newModuleName) => updateEcts(newModuleName, targetIndex)"
/>
```

To understand how is this `update:modelValue` working under the hood, check out [this explanation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#under-the-hood) from the official Vue's documentation.

I'm not sure about this, but it seems this change was introduced on the third version of Vuetify according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483768/v-autocomplete-lost-change-event-in-vuetify-3)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I replaced `@input` with `@update:model-value`:

`@update:model-value="newModuleName => updateEcts(newModuleName, targetIndex)"`

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js, when using v-model with a custom component like v-autocomplete, the component needs to emit an input event to update the bound value. It seems like the issue might be related to how you're handling the input event in your v-autocomplete component.

Let's ensure that the v-autocomplete component emits the input event properly when its value changes. Ensure that v-autocomplete is emitting the input event correctly with the updated value.

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="targetModules[targetIndex]['modulName']"
    :items="moduleNamesAndEcts.map(module => module.name)"
    :rules="rules.text"
    label="Module"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="name"
    @input="(newModuleName) => updateEcts(newModuleName, targetIndex)"
/>
```